# How do I use python for compound interest

Tags: python

I've started making this math app that takes inputs and outputs calculations. Sort of something that will do half of my homework..
But for some reason, it is not printing an answer whenever I try to use simple interest and compound interest...(This is just a prototype of the original so I'll only send the bit where I'm facing an error)

````
r=int(input("what is the rate??"))
t=int(input("time"))
si=(p*r*t)/100
ci=p*(1+r/100)**t-p
operation=str(input('choose from one of these...(make sure the spelling is correct)ci or si'))

def simple_Interest():
      return print(si)
      


def compound_interest():
      return print(ci)
      
      
if "Simple Interest" in operation:
      print(simple_Interest())
elif "compound Interest" in operation:
      print(compound_interest())```
````

Comment: DON'T make your user type the entire phrase, especially since you don't use consistent capitalization.  Just use one letter (like 's' and 'c').  And don't call `print` inside your functions.  The `print` statement doesn't return anything.  Just have the functions return the value, and let the main program print the result.  And it's silly to do both computations and then throw one away.  Do the computation IN the appropriate function.  And you should pass `p`, `r` and `t` to the functions.  Don't use globals.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better design.  Note that I only check the first character for the answer.  The `in` operator is not useful for what you were doing.  Also note that `input` always delivers a string; you never ever need to type `str(input(...))`.

```
p = int(input("Principal?"))
r = int(input("Interest rate?"))
t = int(input("Periods?"))

def simple_interest(p,r,t):
    return (p*r*t)/100

def compound_interest(p,r,t):
    return p*(1+r/100)**t-p
      
operation=input('(c)ompound or (s)imple interest?')
if operation[0] == 's':
    print(simple_interest(p,r,t))
elif operation[0] == 'c':
    print(compound_interest(p,r,t))
else:
    print("Not a good choice.")
```

Comment: I think I get it. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you write `return print(ci)`, you're returning result of `print` function. And this function doesn't return a value, so the output will be `None`. I think it's better to refactor the code like this:

```
def simple_interest(p, r, t):
    si = (p*r*t)/100
    return si


def compound_interest(p, r, t):
    ci = p*(1+r/100)**t-p
    return ci


p = int(input("Principal?")
r = int(input("what is the rate??"))
t = int(input("time"))

operation = input('choose from one of these...(make sure the spelling is correct)ci or si')
      
if operation == 'si':
    print(simple_interest(p, r, t))
elif operation == 'ci':
    print(compound_interest(p, r, t))
else:
    print('Operation is not correct')
```